# (SQLITE) SUM based on cumulative range

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
id | sales |  profit | place
_____________________|______ 
1  |   2   |    1    |  US
2  |   3   |    -    |  SL
3  |   1   |    1    | India
4  |   0   |    -    |  Aus
5  |   2   |    -    |  -
6  |   4   |    1    |  UK
7  |   1   |    -    |  -
```

Now what I want to achieve is, wherever `profit = 1`, I want cumulative `sales` till that point in order of `id` column and the corresponding `place`
i.e.

```
   |  cumulativeSales | place  |
   | ________________ |_______ |
   |     2            |  US    |      //(2)
   |     6            | India  |      //(2+3+1)
   |     12           |  UK    |      //(2+3+1+0+2+4)
```

What query should I write for this?

Comment: This is perfect use case for lag/lead analytic functions.  That is of course assuming your platform supports them.  I am not familiar with sqlite. Check it out.  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried

Comment: It was a typo, i have removed that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer), you can use window functions:

```
SELECT cumulativeSales, place
FROM (SELECT id, place, profit
           , sum(sales) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cumulativeSales
      FROM yourtable)
WHERE profit = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

gives

```
cumulativeSales  place
---------------  ----------
2                US
6                India
12               UK
```

---

The window function form of `sum()` (Indicated by the following `OVER` clause) used in the inner query sums up a given *window* of the result rows. The default behavior with just an `ORDER BY` (Without an explicit framing term) is to use the first row up to all the rows with the same value that's being sorted on, but nothing greater. In other words, it calculates the cumulative sum. For way more detail, see [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).

The outer query just limits the results to those rows where `profit` is 1. If you did that all in one without the subquery, it'd only calculate the cumulative sum of those rows, not all the rows, because window functions are computed after `WHERE` filtering is done.

---

A different approach that uses a correlated subquery to calculate the running total, that works on older versions without window function support:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(sales) FROM yourtable AS t2 WHERE t2.id <= t.id) AS cumulativeSales
     , place
FROM yourtable AS t
WHERE profit = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what `sum(sales) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cumulativeSales` exactly is doing here? Btw thanks a lot! :D You saved a lot of my time

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!